# Android Game Programming questions

Tags: android, state

I am developing a game using Lunar Lander as a tutorial, and I have a couple questions and a problem.

In my game:

- when I press the Home key, onPause() is called. When I click my game's icon to go back in, I get the game screen, but everything is frozen.
- when I press the Back key, onPause() is called. When I click my game's icon to go back in, I get a blank screen.
- In both cases, I do not see my onResume() method being called.

So I am confused as to why this is happening.  Looking at Lunar Lander, there is no onResume().  Why is that?  Since the game thread is stopped in onPause(), how does it start up again?

In my game, I am not sure why onResume() is not being called, but I assume that it never get there since there is some sort of freeze.

Is the Lunar Lander code, or my code, missing something?  Does the LL code handle state changes correctly?  Finally, is there a better web tutorial for handling state changes for games?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, I suppose a new activity is launched on top of the first instance when you click on your application icon. I would say the android documentation is not that clear about it, but if you want to make sure the root activity of your application is only instantiated once you need to add:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

as a property for the activity in your application manifest.

Comment: Thanks... I did add that to the manifest file, but the issue is still happening... it seems like it is frozen or stuck in a loop. I am still unsure why there is no onResume in LL as well.   Could it be that there is no game thread running once I re-enter the app?

Comment: Is your app using only one activity? In that case could you post an extract of the onCreate, onResume, onPause, and onDestroy methods you are using?